# Opensearch document not found after creation

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an Opensearch cluster running with 3 nodes. Sometimes I need to search for the recently created document (less then 1 second after creation). For this I decreased the `refresh_interval` and use `refresh=wait_for` to ensure that the document is available. But sometimes the document is still not available (even after 10 seconds). The only thing i recognized is that my index state was yellow at that time - some shards could not be assigned. What could be a reason for the missing document?

My index request:

```
final IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index);
indexRequest.id(id);
indexRequest.source(data, XContentType.JSON);
indexRequest.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL);
final IndexResponse indexResponse = restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Things I tried to fix it:

- refresh_interval to 100ms
- API call with refresh=wait_for

Comment: That sounds like a highly weird situation. If your indexing call with `refresh=wait_for` returns it means the document is searchable. Can you show in more details the different commands that you run and the results you get vs you expect to get?

Comment: The problem is I was not able to reproduce this intentionally. This somehow appears after weeks in production. I will check the logs of my app und opensearch if there is something  conspicuous. 
But it could not be that the replication or the unavailable shards are the reason for that? Wait_for will ensure that the document is available on all replicas?

Comment: It's perfectly ok to have unassigned replicas (yellow state), replicas are a complete copy of your data, if one is unassigned, it will not be part of the search and the primary will deliver the document. However, if primary shards are unassigned (red state) it's another problem. Can you confirm your cluster is yellow and not red?

Comment: That could've been the problem. I had stability problems on our K8s cluster which forced the opensearch pods to restart sometime. Maybe my cluster state was red at that time. I'm currently working on the monitoring. I will include the state of the cluster and indices. Maybe this will bring me closer the problem. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: Great, glad I could be of help. Feel free to update this thread at anytime and we'll figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was, that my cluster state turned into red some time. After fixing that the problem did not occur again.